# How do get the last payment Date using SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

Currently I'm using below SQL code

```
Last_Value (dbo.TransactionTable.TransDate) 
    over (PARTITION BY dbo.TransactionTable.TransNumber 
          Order by dbo.TransactionTable.TransNumber 
          Rows between UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
as LastPaymentReceived
```

When I run the above SQL script it gives me 06/11/2021.wherein the most recent successful repayment should be 06/08/2020.The code works fine when if customer not missed the payment, Things get complicated when Customer DD returned with transaction posted "Unpaid DD - Instr Cancelled"

However, last payment date for this is 06/11/2021) but this payment was returned unpaid with a transaction posted to the account on 06/11/2021 with transaction posted "Unpaid DD - Instr Cancelled".  Please see the [Transactiondetail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyT7S.png)

Someone can advise me?

Many Thanks
Dan

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. You appear to `order by` a column that isn't pictured.

Comment: You're asking people to guess what the data looks like, what the columns arer orr how many dates there are per transaction, or transactions per date. I'd expect `TransNumber` to be unique so `PARTTITION BY TransNumber` should have no effect - each partition would contain only one row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've given is only a snippet of a single item from a `SELECT` clause. If you want to return multiple rows for different customers, or multiple fields, the answer below may be difficult to integrate into the rest of your code.

```
SELECT TOP 1
   t2.TransDate
FROM
   TransactionTable t2  
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TransactionTable t1
                   WHERE t1.TransDate = t2.TransDate
                   AND t1.Description = 'Unpaid DD - Instr Cancelled')
ORDER BY
   t2.TransDate DESC
```

You will need to add customer filters in the `WHERE` clause for both the main query and the subquery.